# How to improve tests for models with multiple foreign keys (Django)

Tags: django, django-tests

I have a MVP for my testing suite, but my current style will be a beast to maintain. I am running into trouble efficiently writing tests for my model which has two Foreign Keys.

I include my model.py file and my test.py file below:

**models.py**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class ProductCategoryValue(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="categories")
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="products")

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [['category', 'product']]
```

(The idea behind this model structure is that there can be a list of products and a list of categories, with the ProductCategoryValue to serve as the glue between the two lists. The list of categories may change later on in the project and I would like to easily modify the values of each product text with respect to that category. I am open to suggestions to improve this model structure as well!)

**test.py**

```
 #...
 def setUp(self):
    p = Product(name="Touchscreen")
    p.save()
    Product.objects.create(name="Dancer")

    c = Category(name="Use Case", selection_type="bullets")
    c.save()
    Category.objects.create(name="Video Conferencincg", selection_type="text")
    Category.objects.create(name="Multisite", selection_type="Boolean")

    ProductCategoryValue.objects.create(value="foobar", product=p, category=c)
```

Is this the canonical way of writing tests for models which have multiple foreign keys? I'm hoping that there is a more efficient way so that my testing database can be more robust.

Comment: why is this style not robust?

Comment: for what it is worth, in case you want some more real-time data for placeholder values in your model instances, see [factory-boy](pypi.org/project/factory-boy].

Comment: @Abhyudai I will look into factory-boy thank you! I don't like this style because it seems difficult to generate a large number of ProductCategoryValues efficiently (but your suggested package may help with this concern)